# $this->request->isAJAX() undefined method in codeigniter 4.1.1 where is the problem?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm having a problem with my controller, when I try to call `request->isAJAX()` the program returns the error `undefined method`
Note : i'm using codeigniter 4.1.1

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\Mruang;

class Ruang extends BaseController
{
    protected $jenis;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jenis = new Mruang();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'titel' => 'Jenis Ruang'
        ];
        return view('ruang/index', $data);
    }

    public function tampil()
    {
        if ($this->request->isAJAX()) {
            $data = [
                'ruang' => $this->jenis->findAll(),
                'btn'   => true
            ];

            $msg = [
                'data' => view('ruang/data', $data)
            ];

            echo json_encode($msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you provided the code for the `isAJAX()` and `findAll()` methods?

Comment: @Anne Batch : those are CI4 framework methods. Problem won't be there.
@BangBrow : Please make sure your BaseController extends `CodeIgniter\Controller`. And watch out for the upgrade note from 4.0.4 to 4.0.5 : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_405.html If your request object is loaded from the ConfigService then you need to update `app/Config/Services.php` so the class extends `CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService` to allow proper discovery of third-party services

Answer (score 0):

I run your code at my local machine in a CI 4.1.1 installation and it runs ok, at least the `$this->request->isAJAX()` worked as expected.

Look at your `BaseController` and compare it with the default. I pasting the default code bellow

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $helpers = [];

    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
    }
}
```

I also would like to recommend you to look if `Mruang` model has the `findAll()` methods.